# Google calendar feed is limiting items

Tags: php, rss, google-calendar-api

This code is supposed to display all items in my Google calendar RSS, but it is limiting the posts displayed to about 23:

http://james.cridland.net/code/google-calendar.html

My rss feed is here: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ta624s0k5sf002ji485o6d0bvg%40group.calendar.google.com/private-9f18d335ed346643800c76d0c96e286c/basic

Comment: I only get 25 entries in your calendar RSS, so I guess the code is working fine and Google isn't sending everything. How many should be displayed? Where are you using the feed?

Comment: You're right, it was a problem with the RSS. It was just missing an equal sign (=) after "max-results" in a string of code. Now it shows all 50 events.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you’ve changed this line of code:

```
// ...and how many you want to display (leave at 999 for everything)
$items_to_show=999;
```

It should hold 999 entries (or *everything* as it mentions).

There seems to be an error with the script, here (missing '= sign’ after max_results).

Replace with this:

```
// Form the XML address.
$calendar_xml_address = str_replace("/basic","/full?singleevents=true&futureevents=true&max-results=".$items_to_show."&orderby=starttime&sortorder=a",$calendarfeed); //This goes and gets future events in your feed.
```

Comment: This is the page it's displaying on: http://ucmb.uconn.edu/join/2012-preseason-schedule.php. For some reason it only shows up until Thursday (but I have events in Google through Saturday). If I delete the first event, one more event shows up on Thursday. So somehow they are being limited.

Comment: Actually, it was just missing an equal sign (=) after "max-results" in a string of code. Now it shows all 50 events.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to mention that, you can look here `// Form the XML address.
$calendar_xml_address = str_replace("/basic","/full?singleevents=true&futureevents=true&max-results".$items_to_show."&orderby=starttime&sortorder=a",$calendarfeed); //This goes and gets future events in your feed.`